# Why is my python script not creating a GNUPG encrypted file?

Tags: python, gnupg

This code was working before today.

I am using this line to encrypt a file and save it:

```
gpg.encrypt_file(f,recipients=encrypt_key,output= encrypted_file)
```

Here is the code:

gpg = gnupg.GPG()

```
path = 'secure_data' #********** Please make secure_data folder in utils before running
os.chdir(path)
files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)
latest_file = files [-1]


if encrypt_key is not None:
    with open (latest_file, 'rb') as f:
        encrypted_file = latest_file +".gpg"
        gpg.encrypt_file(f,recipients=encrypt_key,output= encrypted_file)
```

The code throws no errors, but no file is created. It worked previously up until today.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share some more details, your code.

Comment: Perhaps you've opened the output file in a different place than you expect? The docs say that encryption can fail silently: https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#encryption. ... more specifically that something is written to the console. Does your program run in a console and does an odd message appear?

Comment: sure.

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    path = 'secure_data' #********** Please make secure_data folder in utils before running
    os.chdir(path)
    files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)
    latest_file = files [-1]


    if encrypt_key is not None:
        with open (latest_file, 'rb') as f:
            encrypted_file = latest_file +".gpg"
            print (f, encrypt_key, encrypted_file)

Comment: What is the value of `encrypted_file`? Did that file exist before you ran this command? Does it work if you delete the file first?

Comment: Edit your code into your question, and ensure it is indented correctly.

Comment: encrypted_file is basically the file name i want the output to be. 

There are no odd messages that appear.

Comment: I have added the code into the question